# How to wrap a referenced c++ class in Cython?

Tags: c++, cython

I'm having Problems to wrap one of the methods of the following mctdhBasis class:

**mctdhBasis.h**:

```
class mctdhBasis
{
public:
    //  mctdhBasis();
    mctdhBasis();
    ~mctdhBasis();

void Initialize(string filename, ControlParameters& config);
.
.
.
//mctdhNode is a custom class, which is defined in mctdhNode.h
const mctdhNode& MCTDHNode(size_t i)const;
.
.
.
};
```

In order to Initializing this class I use:

**ControlParameters.h:**

```
class ControlParameters
{
public:
    ControlParameters();
    ~ControlParameters();

    void Initialize(string configfile, ostream & log);
    .
    .
    .
    };
```

The mctdhNode class is defined in

**mctdhNode.h:**

```
class mctdhNode
: public Node
{
 public:
    mctdhNode();
    mctdhNode(ifstream& file, mctdhNode* up, mctdhNodePosition position_);
    ~mctdhNode();

    void Initialize(ifstream & file, mctdhNode * up_, mctdhNodePosition position_);

    void info(ostream& os=cout)const;
.
.
.
}
```

my cython code looks like follows:

**mctdh.pyx:**

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass ostream:
        ostream& write(const char*, int) except +
    ostream cout

cdef extern from "../MCTDH/ControlParameters.h":
    cdef cppclass ControlParameters:
        ControlParameters() except +
        void Initialize(string, ostream&)

cdef extern from "../MCTDH/mctdhBasis.h":
    cdef cppclass mctdhBasis:
        mctdhBasis() except +
        void Initialize(string, ControlParameters&)
        const mctdhNode& MCTDHNode(size_t i)

cdef extern from "../MCTDH/mctdhNode.h":
    cdef cppclass mctdhNode:
        mctdhNode() except +
        void info(ostream& os=cout)

cdef ControlParameters config
cdef mctdhBasis basis
cdef const mctdhNode & node

cdef ControlParameters PyControlParameters(string para):
    cdef ControlParameters config
    config.Initialize(para, cout)
    return config

cdef void PymctdhNode(para, filename, size_t i):
      config.Initialize(para, cout)
      basis.Initialize(filename, config)
      node[0] = basis.MCTDHNode(i)
```

After compiling these files, I get following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        mctdhNode() except +
        void info(ostream& os=cout)

cdef ControlParameters config
cdef mctdhBasis basis
cdef const mctdhNode & node
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------


mctdh.pyx:32:21: C++ references cannot be declared; use a pointer instead
```

When I change the erroneous line to `cdef const mctdhNode * node`, I get the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    return config

cdef void PymctdhNode(para, filename, size_t i):
      config.Initialize(para, cout)
      basis.Initialize(filename, config)
      node[0] = basis.MCTDHNode(i)
         ^
------------------------------------------------------------


mctdh.pyx:42:10: Assignment to const dereference
```

Finally I changed 
`node[0] = basis.MCTDHNode(i)` to `(&node)[0] = basis.MCTDHNode(i)`

But still it doesn't work:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    return config

cdef void PymctdhNode(para, filename, size_t i):
      config.Initialize(para, cout)
      basis.Initialize(filename, config)
      (&node)[0] = basis.MCTDHNode(i)
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------


mctdh.pyx:42:34: Cannot assign type 'const mctdhNode &' to 'const mctdhNode *'
```

So basically my question is how too declare a variable with the type of 'const mctdhNode &'.

Comment: I guess it should be another way around: `node=&(basis.MCTDHNode(i))` and not `(&node)[0] = basis.MCTDHNode(i)`. However, your question is cluttered with so much unnecessary information (what should I make of `ControlParameters`, the whole pyx-file and so on?) so I'm not really sure what you want. Maybe it is worth taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why does `MCTDHNode` return a reference?  If it's a factory-type function, typically would return by value and let the compiler optimize the copy out (guaranteed in the usual cases)

Comment: Also agree with @ead, you'll get a better answer if this is reduced down to a simpler, compileable example.

Comment: Auto pointer dereference does not work in Cython like it does in C. `ptr[0] = <..>` does not work - in cython code use `val = ptr[0]` and `val = <..>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Auto pointer dereference does not work in Cython like it does in C.

`ptr[0] = <..>` does not work - in cython code instead use:

```
val = ptr[0]  # De-reference
val = <..>   # Assign to ptr[0]
```